# How to auto-sort a bar-chart with a toggle function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've uploaded a **[block](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/73dbb9d6a144476565386f48a2df2e3b)** **(FIXED)** where you can toggle a sorting function.

What I want to add now is some kind of `if` statement when the checkbox is on, and when it is on I want the bars to sort automatically when you change year or category, and when you toggle it again it stops auto-sorting.

I thought a simple

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('myCheckbox').checked) {
    change();
}
```

Within the `update` function would work but nothing happens.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Since `getElementsByClassName` returns a list, it has to be: `if(document.getElementsByClassName('myCheckbox')[0].checked){ etc...`, with the `[0]` as the index. However, I'll not post this as an answer because you'll have to refactor the `change` function for this to work.

Comment: I see, how much code would you have to change in order to make it work? I could post a more simple example if that would help.

Comment: I added an answer, but I'll delete it shortly: the sorting is not working properly. Please copy the details of the answer before I delete it.

Comment: I've copied the answer, really appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started an answer your direct question, but soon realized that your code needed a bit of refactor.  You had a bit too much copy/paste going on with redundant code and too many things drawing.  When coding with `d3` you should try for a single function that does all the drawing.

Here's the [code running](http://plnkr.co/edit/BMjxu8bzhu9WR9gtZwDS?p=preview).

Here's a snippet of the new one update function to rule them all:

```
function update() {

  file = d3.select('#year').property('value') == 'data2017' ? 'data.csv' : 'data2.csv';
  catInt = d3.select('#category').property('value');

    d3.csv(file, type, function(error,data) {

        if(error) throw error;

        var sortIndex = data.map(function(d){ return d.month});

        // Update domain
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
                return d["Category" + catInt]; })
        ]).nice();

        // Update axis
        g.selectAll(".axis.axis--y").transition()
            .duration(750)
            .call(yAxis);
        g.selectAll(".axis.grid--y").transition()
            .duration(750)
            .call(yGrid);

        // Sums and averages
        let sumOfAll = d3.sum(data, function(d) { 
            return d["Category" + catInt];
        });
        let avgValue = d3.sum(data, function(d) { 
            return d["Category" + catInt];
        }) / data.length;

        //sort data
        data.sort( d3.select("#myCheckbox").property("checked")
            ? function(a, b) { return b["Category" + catInt] - a["Category" + catInt]; }
            : function(a, b) { return sortIndex.indexOf(a.month) - sortIndex.indexOf(b.month);})

        // set x domain
        x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.month; }));

        g.selectAll(".axis.axis--x").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .call(xAxis);

        // Update rectangles
        let bars = g.selectAll(".barEnter")
          .data(data, function(d){
            return d.month;
          });

        bars = bars
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
          .attr("class", "barEnter") // Enter data reference
          .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
          .merge(bars);

        bars.transition()
          .duration(750)
          .attr("height", function(d) { 
            return height - y(d["Category" + catInt]); 
          })
          .attr("x", function(d) { 
            return x(d.month); 
          })
          .attr("y", function(d) { 
            return y(d["Category" + catInt]); 
          });

    bars.exit().remove();

        // Update text on rectangles
        let textUpdate = g.selectAll(".textEnter")
          .data(data, function(d){
            return d.month;
          });

        textUpdate = textUpdate.enter()
        .append("text")
        .style("text-shadow","1px 1px #777")
        .attr("class", "textEnter") // Enter data reference
        .attr("text-anchor","middle")
        .attr("font-size",11)
        .attr("fill","#fff")
        .merge(textUpdate);

        textUpdate.transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("y", function(d) { 
                return y(d["Category" + catInt]) + 15; 
                })
            // Update text value
            .text( function(d) { 
                return d["Category" + catInt]; 
            })
            .attr("x", function(d) { 
            return x(d.month) + x.bandwidth()/2; 
        })

        // Update sum and avg value
        g.selectAll("#totalValue").transition()
            .duration(750)
            .text(sumOfAll + " Category " + catInt)
        g.selectAll("#avgValue").transition()
            .duration(750)
            .text(formatValue(avgValue))
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I updated my [Block](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/73dbb9d6a144476565386f48a2df2e3b) and altered the conditional operator to an if statement, would this make the code redundant? Would a multiple ternary evaluation still be preferable? (if you wanted to add yet another csv file)

Comment: @RobertAndersson, no, your if statement is fine.  For more then two options, I would use an if over a nest ternary.