# Transitioning the clipPath when the data is updated

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48284863/7473025) question.

Here's the code: [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z1pf5x7Uel7fmzp9Lsaa?p=preview)

What I'm trying to do now is to update the `clipPath` in unison with everything else and I can't quiet figure it out

I've tried various methods to make it transform in a smooth way but get the same result everytime.
The method used in the plunker is the following:

```
defs.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip-above")
.append("rect");

g.selectAll("#clip-above>rect")
  .transition().duration(durations)
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", y(1));
```

But no matter what method I use the clipPath just jumps to the newly calculated area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense to me why you are removing and re-appending the `<clipPath>` every time you run the `update` function. Also, there are a lot of other things that should be changed: for instance. why are you using `d3.csv` inside the `update` function? Therefore, I suggest you post this code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), so we can suggest the adequate changes (such question would be off topic here at S.O.).

Back to your question:

Append the `<clipPath>` outside the `update` function:

```
var defs = g.append("defs");

var clipAbove = defs.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip-above");

var clipAboveRect = clipAbove.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", 0);

var clipBelow = defs.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip-below");

var clipBelowRect = clipBelow.append("rect")
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", 0);
```

And, in the function, just do the transition:

```
clipAboveRect.transition().duration(durations)
    .attr("height", y(1));

clipBelowRect.transition().duration(durations)
    .attr("y", y(1))
    .attr("height", height - y(1));
```

Here is the updated Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/XcQOvupaS3hLU136blUk?p=preview

PS: If you want an explanation to your problem, a transition goes from a *start* value to an *end* value. You need to have both for the transition to work.

Comment: "why are you using d3.csv inside the update function?" Because in my finished chart I'll have more than one csv file to toggle, like i've done [here](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/d73ef3eb17287b30a87290cce57e2d98) . I got the idea from Mark here on S.O in an answer he gave me.

Comment: No, that's a wrong approach! `d3.csv` is asynchronous, and because of that you should not do it inside a function called by a dropdown menu. You have to download **all** the data needed to the dataviz at once. You don't see the difference because the CSV is probably small, but the day you get a big CSV (or a slow connection) your code will give a bad user experience.

Comment: Intersting, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46745967/7473025) his answer btw, I'll post a question on code review later about it, and thank you very much for your answer